# While alter table adding foreign key getting error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a foreign key in SQL Server to an existing table, but I'm getting an error. Could any one please help me?

Note: `objid` is present in both table 1 & table 2

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_41_PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY
    FOREIGN KEY (Table1 PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY) REFERENCES table2(objid);
```

Error:

> FK_40_PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY. The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.table2", column 'objid'.

Comment: Very odd to have a PRICE_QTY referencing an id column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the error in the syntax, I think there are some values in the `objid` column that doesn't exist in the `PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY` table. You have to check the values between the two columns. This is why you are creating the foreign key to prevent such things.

Comment: In table1 we do  have column "PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY" & OBJID apart from this table 2 we have "OBJID", whatesle I'm missing why I'm getting syntax error.

Comment: The reason Im getting error some of value nullable.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be something more like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_41_PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY
    FOREIGN KEY (PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY) REFERENCES table2(objid);
```

You don't need to qualify the column name.

Comment: Even i tried with what u provided still getting the same error.

Comment: @Shilpi . . . Is `table2.objid` declared as the primary key?  Foreign key relationships should be to primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Do a quick check on you column 'objid' and don't write

```
 FOREIGN KEY (Table1 PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY) REFERENCES table2(objid);
```

It should be more like:

```
FOREIGN KEY (PRICE_INST2PRICE_QTY) REFERENCES table2(objid);
```

without table1, because you're working in table1.

Comment: Yes even if m not provinding Table 1 still getting the same issue